# In Queen's address on Corona Virus, does she say that Britain does not have a past it can be proud of?

Tags: monarchy

In the Queen's address to the Commonwealth on the Corona Virus, she says at 1:15:

"The pride in who we are is not a part of our past. It defines our present and our future."
What does the Queen mean by this? Is she saying that Britain does not have a past it can be proud of?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2klmuggOElE&feature=youtu.be&t=115

Comment: Perhaps the question is better suited for the English Language & Usage site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The queen is saying that the pride of the British people, is not *merely* pride over past behavior, but is pride in themselves as they are now and as they move forward. She is not denying that the British should be proud of their past; she is suggesting that their past is not what *defines* their pride. Their pride is defined by who they are.

Comment: I read it not as "pride over past behavior" but rather "pride only existed in the past", IOW "our pride is present (not just past) and defines etc.".